# Update Service Reference does not work when the [OperationContract] method have colletion as argument

Tags: wcf, operationcontract, service-reference

I have a very strange problem which I do not understand.
I have my WCF interface which methods are decorated with the `[OperationContract]` attribute.
Then I have my Service Reference folder which I update every time I change my interface.

Everything works fine until in my interface I will declare a method that takes any collection as the argument (`List<T>`, `Array<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` etc.).

Then when I run the "Update Service Reference" it finish without any errors, but the generated `Reference.cs` file is empty.

In the "Configure Service Reference" window I have the "Collection Type" set to "System.Collection.Generic.List"

Anyone knows why I cannot use collection types as argument in my Operation Contract method? Or how to fix it?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen when the type `T` of your `List<T>` is not serailizeable or a DataContract.

Also try and uncheck the

> "Reuse Types in Referenced Assemblies"

in your configuration.

Comment: I am using only collections of Guid, int and string types.

Comment: What can the "Reuse Types in Referenced Assemblies" option change?

Comment: Should I have it in case when I am not using my custom types, only .NET types?